# How to Achieve a Similar Printed Aesthetic in PS/Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, photoshop-effects, effects, illustrator-effects

### How to Achieve a Similar Printed Aesthetic in PS/Illustrator?

I've been trying to figure this out for a while, and haven't been able to find great tutorials anywhere so thought I'd ask here.

I'm trying to figure out how people achieve this look in Illustrator/Photoshop where the artwork looks very printed.

In the below image example, there's some Roughening happening, and it seems like there's more going on than that, where the lines almost seem sort of diffuse.

Is it really just roughened with some careful placement of grit texture around the edges or something else?

[image: By Rise Wise on Dribbble]

Comment: Did my below answer help? You could also add some shine to the text to give it a more of a printed gloss look, or a slight Bevel, to give it a raised or indented feel. It's a nice logo :)

Answer (score 2):

## COSTA MESA TEXTURED PAPER EFFECT

This was possibly done in Photoshop. This is how...

---

1. Create paper coloured canvas by using the non-destructible solid colour fill layer option.

[image]

2. Now turn that layer into a **Smart Filter** layer.

[image]

To produce that textured paper feel, select the **Camera Raw** filter

[image]

3. Navigate to the **FX** tab and use the **Grain** settings seen in the image, then press OK.

[image]

4. Now create a circle using the **Ellipse Tool**

[image]

5. Using the **Text Tool** (T), hover over the top-center **point** until you see the **I-beam** with a wavy line and start to type. The text will follow the circular path.

[image]
[image]

6. Now select your text layer, right click and select **Blending Options**
7. Navigate to the **Stroke** area and use the setting I've set in the image.

[image]

8. Now duplicate the layer, set the **Fill** of original layer to **0** then click into the **Blending Options** of the new layer and use these settings.

[image]
[image]
[image]

9. Delete your shape layer and you're all done.
10. If you want a softer paper looking, turn your layer into a **Smart Filter** layer and apply some **Gaussian Blur**.

[image]

[image]

If you play around with the stroke settings you'll be able to match original COSTA MESA pretty much exactly. It will also look more like the original image if the same font is used.

Apologies for the missing **A**.

Comment: No need to apologize, the cost can be substantial if one copies an existing piece.of art. +1 for fine receipe.

Answer (score 0):

**Illustrator**

From an outline illustration and text

[image]

Outline the text and Expand Appearance to the illustration strokes

Apply **Roughen** and **Feather**

[image: Roughen]

Fill it with an old print look color

[image]

**Expand Appearance** and **Simplify** paths

[image: End]

Comment: Kvnmclse was looking for a more roughened diffused, git look. Like the bleeding edges on textured print paper.